# Python - Beautiful Soup scraper returning some, but not all, text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the top 100 jobs in the United States from this [list](https://www.ranker.com/list/most-common-jobs-in-america/american-jobs). When I run this code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.ranker.com/list/most-common-jobs-in-america/american-jobs'
page_opened = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_opened, 'html.parser')
jobs_soup = soup.find_all('span','listItem__title')
print(jobs_soup)
```

Beautiful Soup returns what I would expect, job titles surrounded by  tags,except it only goes to "Secondary School Teachers", which is only #25 out of 100 jobs. I've used Beautiful Soup this same way on other webpages without problems. Is there anything funky about the webpage/my code which is causing the output to be incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the network tab open in the developer tools of my browser, I saw that XHR requests were being made as I scrolled and some of the responses contained list items. You were only able to get the first 24 items because these requests were not being triggered. The url for one of the requests was:

https://cache-api.ranker.com/lists/354954/items?limit=20&offset=50&include=votes,wikiText,rankings,openListItemContributors&propertyFetchType=ALL&liCacheKey=null

By changing the limit to 100 and the offset to 0 I was able to get the top 100 jobs:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

# I removed the other query parameters and it still seems to work
url = 'https://cache-api.ranker.com/lists/354954/items?limit=100&offset=0'
resp = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(resp.read())
job_titles = [item['name'] for item in data['listItems']]
print(len(job_titles))
print([job_titles[0], job_titles[-1]])
```

Output:

```
100
['Retail salespersons', 'Cleaners of vehicles and equipment']
```